# Is this plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, plagiarism

This is just example imitating real question/answers with same level of difficulty:

Question:

> In Java, how can I replace one or more continues dots with only one dot like "f.o.o....bar." -> "f.o.o.bar."?
>
> I tried with `myString.replace(".+",".")` but it doesn't change anything.

Answer1:

> `replace` method accepts literals, not regex. You wan to use `replaceAll`.
> Also you need to escape `.` since it is regex metacharacter (you can use `"\\."` for that).
> Last thing is that Strings in Java are immutable so invoking `myString.replaceAll` doesn't change string from `myString` reference, but it creates (and returns) new one with replaced values, so you should store it somewhere like in `myString` reference. In short, your code can look like:
>
> `yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\\.+",".");`

Answer2 (posted 10 minutes after Answer1):

> Based on suggestion from Answer1 you can run below code and see that it solves your problem (thanks @Answer1Author):

```
public class TestX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "f.o.o...bar.";
        myString = myString.replaceAll("\\.+", ".");
        System.out.println(myString);
    }
}
```

---

As you see there is some general question and answer which explains the problem fully and with simple solution.

Now ten minutes after correct answer new one appears which contains only runnable example showing that Answer1 was correct.

Is this new answer OK, or not? I am asking since few weeks ago I flagged such answer with description

> It is basically duplicate of already posted answer [link]. It just wraps solution in runnable method

and till this day my flag is active so I am not sure if mods are too busy or maybe this behaviour is not so bad as I think it is.

While ***I agree that this technically may not be plagiarism***, I still see such answers as duplicates so I left a comment(s) under it explaining why such behaviour is (at least IMO) not correct, and down-voted it. Can I do something more about it (except posting link to this answer on meta, I don't want to cause lynch which could discourage this user from farther participating in SO - I didn't see any other answers of this type in his/her profile so it seems to be one time mistake)?

Comment: It's not plagiarism, but it's not exactly great style.

Comment: When copying a line like `yourString.replaceAll("\\.+",".")` is considered plagiarsim, then **every** programmer has committed plagiarism **millions** of times. `System.out.println("Hello world");`. Of course, concerning the role as an *answer* here, it may not have been necessary, and arguing about whether a MCVE in this case adds value to an answer is probably nitpicking (although I don't think so in this case...)

Comment: *mySt**ir**ng*?

Comment: Two totally different answers one is a theory or described way of fixing it - the other is an actual implementation / algorithm.  They both support the OP.  To me no plagiarism exists.

Comment: @JonH So do you think it would be OK to lets say go to PHP questions, take code from best answers, wrap it in `<?...?>` and as separate answer while including link to original answer?

Comment: Please reread what I just said.

Comment: @JonH "*Two totally different answers one is a theory or described way of fixing it - the other is an actual implementation / algorithm.* that is not entirely true, first answer contains beside explanation *complete* code which solves problem, second answer just wraps solution from firat answer in *main* method making it easier to test.

Comment: Anyway I have a feeling that I give wrong title to question from my post. I wasn't trying to focus only if this is plagiarism, but more if this particular answer (adding very basic informations) should be posted as separate answer. IMO it is nothing more than (maybe even useful but still) comment.

Comment: But Pshemo the context around it supports that it isn't plagiarism.  He / she credits or mentions original author - maybe it helped the OP.  To me it isn't plagiarism.

Comment: @JonH Like I said, I agree that this may not be plagiarism, but what bothers me is that if should such answers (one which doesn't add anything important) be posted as answers. I see them as comments saying "I thing your answer is correct @ Answer1Author, this is how I tested it : ...".

Comment: Pshemo - not much you can do, look at this answer I posted years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2502095/168703 then someone posts the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/a/2502122/168703 I called him out on it..but nothing happened...you just learn to live with it...my example is much worse than yours..its almost a complete duplicate to my code even variable names where the same.

Comment: @JonH I am not the author of Answer1 so it doesn't bother me that much. I was witness of such behaviour and did what I thought was correct to discourage it (leave comment with explanation/down-vote/flag). Point of posting this question was to make sure that I did correct thing (which I now know that flagging may have been overreaction, but rest of actions seems to be right). Anyway thanks for your interest and opinion :)

Comment: I've had the opposite of this happen where someone edited my answer that wrapped the solution in a working example and replaced it with [just the one line](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14971637/revisions)

Comment: @JeremyThompson Generally it is acceptable to remove from code examples unnecessary parts like (in Java) declaration of `main` method along with class name containing it (if this class doesn't include other methods used in example) and imports to standard classes. In case of your linked answer it seems that main solution was code placed inside your method, so method signature was something extra, but not needed (method name is correct but irrelevant, returned type is same as expected in question, method doesn't use any arguments which type could be important), so I would agree with this edit.

Comment: @Pshemo easy test to see if your right, wrap the answer1 in Public Class{} and see if it runs.

Comment: @CalvinSmith I am not sure what you are trying to say. Question is not about if Answer1 is right or wrong, or how to test it; but if posting separate answer which provides only testcase proving correctness of already posted answer is acceptable and if/how we should prevent it. I originally thought that it could be plagiarism but now I know that it is not, but still I don't see such post as worthy of being separate answer. For me such answer is nothing more than comment saying "your answer is correct, here is how we can test it : [..code or link to testing code..]".

Comment: your comment, `So do you think it would be OK to lets say go to PHP questions, take code from best answers, wrap it in <?...?> and as separate answer while including link to original answer?`. That is not what the poster did. He created an enviroment, tested the solution, and posted his results. At what point is it acceptable to do so. If the answer was 2 lines is that ok? or 3 or 10 or 20?

Comment: @CalvinSmith Wait, what? How does number of lines have anything to do with what I said? I am sorry but I may be too tired or my English is not good enough to understand what you are trying to say :/ Also "*He created an enviroment, tested the solution, and posted his results*" so I will wrap PHP answer in `<?..?>` will provide some "foo","bar" data, execute such script and include screenshots of generated page. Do you think that such post should be included as separate answer or should it be more like comment or even edit to original answer?

Comment: Most people would not consider it plagiarism if the source is referenced, as it was in this case.

Comment: @Pshemo I don't like editing another persons answer normally, and I cant't imagine trying to read a code example inside of a comment.

Comment: @CalvinSmith I also don't like editing other people answers, that is why before using "edit" option I try to describe as comments how post can be improved (I also include some links to code examples stored in ideone.com or pastebin.com if code example is too long for comment). If I don't get response in few hours then I do edit. This way author of post knows what I did and (thanks to comment) why I think it was appropriate. If author will not agree with my edit then I would say posting it as separate answer would be OK because it is only thing left I could do to make this improvement visible.

Comment: At first glance your answer looks like it doesn't contain executable code, just suggestions. (Yeah the one-liner is buried at the bottom, but the code-formatting everywhere camouflages it). Here is my strong advice from personal experience of both reading and writing many answers: 1) move the code snippet to the top 2) Put your comments in bullet-style form (if at all possible, underneath) 3) Only if you absolutely need to, preamble and summarize the code by one line of explanatory text (max 80 chars) e.g. "Here is how to do it using replaceAll(), which accepts regexes, unlike replace():*

Comment: So, by making your answer very clear, easy to speed-read, and making it clearer that it contains executable code, you remove most incentive for others to rewrite it.

Comment: @smci Just to be clear, I am not author of any of *real* question/answers which made me write this question. These are just examples showing level of difficulty of real question and amount of details in posted answers. But thanks for your input, I agree that answer could be improved with better formatting. About placing solution at top - I am not a fan. I want to make sure that someone will be able to understand solution before using it, so explanation of all problems should be first. I agree that it could prevent situation described in this question, but I don't like the cost.

Comment: @Pshemo A lot of time has passed since the question was posted. Can you tell please what your current attitude towards duplicated answers? As I understood, it doesn't make sense to flag such answers. So what the most suitable way to react? Down-vote? Leave a comment? It doesn't seem to be pointless - let's,  someone has posted the code that differs only in variable names, after many hours, because this person has definitely seen the original answer and realized what they were doing. Take a breath and move on?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I stopped playing "reputation hunting" game few years ago, and after SO stopped being neutral, or taking into consideration opinions of community I also limited my participation to minimum. I no longer care that much (we can discuss things on meta but in the end what is acceptable/site policy is not our decision). Anyway my personal actions ware (1) checking time difference - few minutes was OK, people are not reading/writing with same speed (2) looking for *possible improvement* in "duplicate". If it could benefit someone let it stay (variable renaming can be improvement)

Comment: (3) leave comment asking for improvements - if duplicate author is still active on the site (4) in case of lack response in acceptable amount of time downvote and if duplicate is ***100%*** pure duplicate for farming reputation flag it (don't be bothered by fact that flag may be rejected, in such cases ask on meta about *this specific case* to learn more - maybe you ware wrong, but maybe you ware not).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for your responses. I've tried to exercise these approaches. Until now, the last one (with flags) happened to be fruitless.

Comment: I've encountered a strange situation on StackOverflow. It in't related to duplicates (I didn't find a description of a similar case on meta) may I ask your advice in a chart room to avoid clattering these comments?  It's not urgent.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko "the last one (with flags) happened to be fruitless" my guess is that this may be related to *exodus of expert moderators* which happened few years ago (example: [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389906)). Now mods which remained have more work (since there are less people). Investigating duplicates may require more time than other kind of flags so they may skip your flag for now. Anyway you can always ask community by creating question like this one (I would rather not participate in it for personal reasons).

Comment: If you don't want to cause meta-effect by linking to "suspected posts" then don't link to them but create similar examples. But TBH it is hard to "protect" actual posts which cause you to ask the question if you are one of the sides, since people may still find it anyway by browsing your activity (you may explicitly ask them to not provide links to avoid meta-effect, OR ask from different/unrelated account). On the other hand problem with analogy is that it is still only analogy, so showing "actual" data - pointing to actual posts - makes question clearer (but that is your decision to make).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Sorry, I don't feel qualified to represent current policies of SO regarding community management. Also you are probably overestimating my experience regarding such situations since in my time here I faced it very rarely (I am not sure if it even ware more situations after the one described in this question), so your opinion is as good as mine. Regarding *ad hominem* attacks you are free to flag them to bring moderator attention to them (and perhaps to topic of conversation which caused them). Good luck!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No, the author of answer 2 credits the author of answer 1. For it to be plagiarism the perpetrator would have to claim the work as their own.

Answers that explain the same thing, but in different language are fine. What is not fine is copying answers wholesale and passing them of as your own, or posting *very late* answers to questions already having satisfactory answers, with minor changes to try and farm reputation.

Your example is fine. Perhaps not great style, but there is nothing untoward about it.

Comment: Note that, while definitions of plagiarism vary, it can be considered plagiarism when, "copying so many words or ideas from a source that it makes up the majority of your work, whether you give credit or not" ([source](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism/)).  Just copying someone else's content, even if you state that it is yours, without actually adding value, can potentially be plagarism.  It's the once case that doesn't involve claiming another's work as your own (implicitly or explicitly).

Comment: @Servy: note that plagiarism is not *that* easily defined, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism); the site you link to is a sponsored site from a software house producing plagiarism detection tools. I'm sure US law can be a good starting point in defining what constitutes plagiarism here too, but answer posts may not even be long enough to be able to apply that rule.

Comment: I opened with `definitions of plagiarism vary`.  I just picked some wording from the first hit on Google that I've found, but it's a sentiment that is certainly not exclusive to just that source.  It's also important to separate out "plagiarism" from "violation of copyright" in a legalistic sense (or more broadly "legally actionable violations of intellectual property rights").  They are rather separate concepts.  There is a fair bit of overlap, but they're certainly not synonymous.  Not all violations of copyright are plagiarism, not all types of plagiarism are a violation of copyright.

Comment: OK, I agree that this may not be plagiarism sine author pointed to the source, but would you agree that we can consider it as duplicate since such answer doesn't add any new and important informations? If so how do you think I deal with it? I already posted comment explaining that such behaviour is not correct (with which contained some points about why I thing that it is not OK to post such answers), downvoted and flagged it. Maybe my flag was not clear enough? Maybe I should flag again with longer explanation.

Comment: @Pshemo You can certainly feel that the original content that that the author provided was not of value, and that as a result the answer was not helpful.  When an answer is not helpful you can indicate that through voting.  It is not a reason to flag a post for moderator attention.

Comment: @Servy: we agree then :-) And yes, copyright and plagiarism are distinct concepts, related but separate.

Comment: @Servy It is not that I only consider it as unhelpful (in that case it would be OK to just downvote and leave it). Problem is that I see it as form of cheating to get some reputation which IMO may lower standards of SO so it probably should be moderated.

Comment: @Pshemo: there is nothing about such answers that requires moderator intervention. The post doesn't need to be deleted, there is no need to discipline the second author with a stern talking to or suspensions, etc. If you feel the answer is not helpful, then vote on it accordingly.

Comment: @Pshemo Nothing about the post is violating any rules.  It's citing the source, and it's adding original content to the citation.  The only problem that I can see with the post is that the original content that is added isn't actually helpful, but rather pretty much just noise.

Comment: OK, it seems I was too hasty with flagging it then. Thank you both for your time MartijnPieters and @Servy.

Comment: @Pshemo _"you agree that we can consider it as duplicate since such answer doesn't add any new and important informations"_ You can't generalize like that. The second answer provides a "compilable test case" in order for the OP to validate the first answer. Depending on the person reading that answer, she might consider this "addition" as useless or valuable. In either case, just vote.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux It may not look like it but I wasn't trying to generalize. I agree that there are some not so popular technologies where instructions of how to use answer1 could be very useful. I was referring to specific case where answer is about very popular language, so similarly if question was about PHP answer2 would be in form "you need to wrap code from answer1 in `<? codeFromAnswer1 ?>`" which while being true, is not really that necessary since even I (not PHP developer) know about. IMO answers providing this level of informations should be comments (we also can vote them as useful).

Comment: To clarify "What is not fine is copying answers wholesale and passing them of as your own": [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26460553/2564301) is [plagiarism](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6207927/2564301).

Comment: @Jongware: wheee, that user has done that more than once.

Comment: Yup, I flagged about half a dozen this far and they were accepted, but it seems so far no mod has had the time to check the rest. Funny thing is, I only noticed this behavior because he copied just about the entire [About] page as "answer" to another meta question.

Comment: @Jongware: the OP is now in the (hasty) process of cleaning up.

Answer (score 8):

IMHO you have every right to be irritated by the second answer, especially (but not exclusively) if it was accepted as a solution and/or awarded more upvotes than yours.

The second answer is basically worthless, because it doesn't improve or give alternative to yours.

If the original question was ***How to write an executable Java program that replaces ...?***, than, in my book, out of 100 points, the second answer would get 20 and yours 80.
Writing a main method in Java is that much ubiquitous.

Comment: I am not the author of Answer1. I just saw such situation and was curious if that was OK or not (IMO it was very close to being plagiarism). I decided to downvote Andswer2 and leave a comment with explanation why I think such behaviour is incorrect. I also flagged it as possible duplicate of Answer1 but now I think this may have been overreaction.

Comment: OK, so replace the word `you` with `first answer author` :)  But, no, I don't think you overreacted. That kind of answers should be deleted. Otherwise someone could wrap all java related code in main methods. No value there!

Comment: Even though the original questioner didn't ask for spoon-feeding of the complete solution, other readers of the question may find these extra details useful. I frequently post answers like the first one, and someone (maybe the questioner) comments, asking how the change fits into the original code.

Comment: I mentioned that: _If the question was ..._, then it's valuable. Otherwise we could repost all answers on the site with something unrelated, on the assumption that someone might find it useful (which I also mentioned). No, we want focused answers that answer a specific question well. Then, if you want to go to `x` direction from there, just search _How to x_. Second author wrapped it in `main` method. I might think that wrapping the code in a helper class's `static` method would be helpful for someone. You might think that anonymous inner class is in order,... **One thing and one thing well**.

Comment: TLDR IMHO, as a secondary answerer, you should provide more specifics only if question author asks for them, or you're posting a general usage pattern that goes well with it. Which `main` method certainly is not.

Answer (score 5):

The second answer takes the essential part of the answer (String.replaceAll) and surrounds it with a simple example. The creative effort is not very high. The benefit for the question is equally low. Moreover people will have to read more answers to get to the quite simple solution here. In the end this is even bad for SO.

Instead of adding a nearly identical answer why not editing the first one. This will not give reputation (which is the true problem here) but would improve SO much, much more.

It's not plagiarism if you cite correctly but it's also next to useless if you mostly just copy an already existing answer and therefore the label "not useless" applies here. This means downvoting.

If this would not be true I could go and marginally improve millions of existing answers on SO not via edits but via newly submitted answers. Not much good this would do to SO.