# What to do with duplicated answers?

Tags: discussion

What should we do when there are two answers that are the same?

If I see two answers with some difference between their publication time, and the newer contains almost exactly the same code as than the older:

- Is this a kind of violation of the rules?
- What is the correct behaviour for this?

**EDIT**

I would like to share with you this 2 answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357141/2815099
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680511/2815099

The first (1.) is the oldest and is selected as correct answer, the second one is newer (it was writed 3 years after) and it's almost same content as 1. with other words

Comment: How trivial is the problem? Unless the second answer is an exact copy, there usually is no issue here. Different people can easily come up with the same solution, for example.

Comment: That is what I suposed, but I weren't sure about this

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Related: [Is this plagiarism?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275604/is-this-plagiarism)

Comment: Down vote the last answer posted then post a comment "How is this different from Bob's answer?". Such comments often lead to the poster adding further details to their answer, after which you can remove the down vote and possibly even up vote.

Comment: There is a related problem when somebody figures out a good answer and goes and pastes it to multiple questions.  Sometimes, the questions should be closed as duplicates; sometimes, the poster might be just a bit too eager; and sometimes, it's actually okay.  These tend to be visible in the review queue, but there is no good indication of what action we should take.

Comment: related: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243243/vote-to-delete-answers-as-duplicates-of-earlier-answers) (at MSE)

Comment: Your example aren't duplicates since the second one points out a limitation the first one does not. But you could argue that the second one should have been a comment on the first answer.

Answer (score 13):

> two answers with some difference between their publication time

The difference in times matters. Multiple users will often post answers on a question just after it has been asked. The easier the problem, the most likely this is to happen, and the easier the problem, the most likely all answers are going to resemble one another. Unless one answer is a *cut and paste of another*, there is really nothing to do.

Sometimes someone will post an answer that presents the same solution as an earlier one but will post much later than the earlier one. If it is a cut and paste, then it should be downvoted and flagged for moderator attention as plagiarism. If it is the same solution but expressed *significantly differently*, there's no problem. There are multiple ways to explain an issue and its solution. Someone might understand the later answer better than the earlier one.

It is when the newer answer posted significantly later than an earlier one is presenting essentially the same solution as the earlier one and does not explain it differently that in my view there *is* a actionable problem. In my opinion the new answer adds no value to the site. However, in my experience, flags on these posts are declined.

Comment: Of course flags in the last case will be declined.  Posting an unhelpful answer isn't grounds for moderator attention.  When you see an unhelpful answer the correct response is to downvote it.

Comment: @Servy See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572/1906307) by Robert Harvey: "Answers that merely parrot information that someone has already provided earlier (for some significant amount of time earlier) in lesser detail don't add any value. Cast a custom moderator flag, explaining the problem ("This answer is a duplicate of an answer already posted two years ago")." If the newer answer explains "in lesser detail[s]" it is obviously not a verbatim copy of the earlier one.

Comment: And yet you've said yourself that in actual practice such flags tend to get declined.

Comment: It's just not as "of course" as you think.

Comment: @Servy which is exactly the problem. Those flags tend to be refused even though they fit Robert's way of seeing this (probably by reviewers like you :)) Shouldn't you maybe be changing your viewpoint on the matter?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I'm not a moderator.  I can't decline flags.  Only mods can decline flags.  It's been well established that moderators shouldn't be deleting answers just because those answers are of low quality; the answers should instead be downvoted.  I have no idea why Robert would say otherwise, as that's simply not the site's policy.

Comment: The problem with downvoting is that [a lot more users carelessly upvote duplicate answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386688/1269037). The few of us who care about site quality have no chance against that.