# Was I in the right to flag these answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, plagiarism

Reading SO's [long standing policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275954/what-to-do-with-duplicated-answers) on dealing with duplicate answers, I came across this question which had many answers: [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332289/4909087)

Here's [one highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib/41717533#41717533) posted in Jan 2017, with a particular solution and two other answers posted months later that are almost cookie-cutouts of the original:

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629427/4909087), posted in August, 2017
- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45979822/4909087), also posted in August, 2017

So, these two answers have been posted almost 6 months after the first one, and both have received many upvotes. It is not clear whether these users plagiarised the answers, and while I may not be an expert in this particular tag, those answers seem reasonably identical to be flagged.

So I did. 4 days ago. These flags are still pending (as of Oct 20th), which makes me doubt their validity. Should I have raised these flags in the first place?

Comment: question has almost 800K views, there are less then 600 such questions all time. For cases like that, meta looks like more appropriate venue to handle issues than flags ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335548/839601)). At the very least I would point exceptionally high amount of views in flag message, to help moderators see the context ([Atwood's cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) guidelines are probably worth referring too)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler https://puu.sh/y3BV7/66d9f4d3b4.png Did the ninja edit :p

Comment: Curious — apparently sub-second timing differences!  I wonder if that's a separate MSO question (how did two simultaneous, identical edits both get accepted?)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's a known thing. Not a bug, just the way the system was designed.

Comment: For a bit of context, we are getting a *lot* of plagiarism flags lately, and these flags take quite a while to handle thoroughly/correctly. So, they tend to stay pending for a while, even longer than other types of flags. Plus, the moderator flag queue is hovering around 500 these days, which is quite a lot. Please be patient. 4 days is not all that long.

Comment: Earlier this year, I had a custom flag pending for more than a month. Other people have reported the similar time-frames. In fact, [in chat we were joking about flags getting birthday cake if they were pending for more than a month](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37112804#37112804). Your expectation of 4 days being too long for how fast flags will be handled appears to be a bit skewed by the excellent job that's been done over the last few months by all of our moderators.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We don't leave flags pending because they're wrong, in that case we will decline them. We just hadn't gotten to them yet.

Comment: Understandable, but I've never had a (custom) flag pending for nearly 4 days. Is that usual?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. We don't have great visibility into the average flag handling time, or the time by flag type. We generally work through the queue from the top down, but the "top" isn't necessarily the oldest; there's some kind of priority algorithm in place.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for addressing the flags, I believe my question has been answered.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the custom flag queue is pretty much all stuff pointing out plagiarism or untoward/suspicious behaviour which are the more grey areas of flags that require investigation which takes time. So when we do get around to them sometimes after investigating it's still not clearcut so instead of clearing the flag we might leave it for a bit as a reminder to check back later to see if new information is available to make a judgement call or let another mod have a look who might see something we originally missed.

Comment: Sometimes, there are [meta posts when a flag is handled too quickly, as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299708/when-a-flag-is-quickly-accepted-as-helpful-will-moderators-still-look-into-it).  ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ flag handling time is [enormously variable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309628/1709587) due to the way that mods filter flags. It's perfectly normal to be waiting around for a month for one particular flag to get handled all while having dozens of others in the meantime all be reliably chomped through by the mods within a couple of minutes of being raised.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Don't use the time taken for a decision on a flag as an indicator of right or wrong. Either the mods haven't gotten to your flag yet or the decision may be pending discussion on their end. I've probably had at least a couple that had gone on for over a month or close. And the response I got back indicated that there were internal discussions on how they should be handled. But they weren't your ordinary plagiarism or offensive posts kind of deal, but much deeper.