# Bad review audit item in Late Answers queue

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

Yesterday, I failed an audit in the Late Answers queue. The answer **was** clearly... an answer and **it hadn't been plagiarised** from other answers in the same question. It just repeated what they said - just a *poor* attempt at answering the question.

So, I clicked *No Action Needed*, but then I got *STOP! Look and Listen!...*

The review audit (screenshot):

> [image]

The content of the answer:

> Make a container for the image with relative position. Than use absolute position on image. Hope that will work

I disagree with the automatic comment by [Bsquare ℬℬ](https://stackoverflow.com/u/10524205): this is an answer.

Also, I am not sure how this came to the Low Quality Posts Queue. A mod-flag, a comment, or a downvote would be enough here.

I believe, that in the Late Answers queue people should not go to the question page and check all of the other answers to compare them with the current one. The should check for spam, rude or abusive, not an answer or very low quality. I went *No Action Needed* because flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

What I want to learn here, is **why this answer was put as an audit**. It is not good as an audit. It should have never been deleted as NAA/VLQ from the LQP reviewers, so I should have never failed/seen it.

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520175) (10k+) while the review audit I failed can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22283713).

Comment: That's the Late Answers queue, not the LQP queue - in Late Answers, an "attempt at an answer" isn't enough, you should give feedback of whether it's a *good* or *bad* answer. Since this answer lacks any code and isn't particularly clear, it's not good - you should have voted down or commented to prompt the author to make it better.

Comment: @CertainPerformance what I mind is that the question was deleted as NAA from LQP, that's why it was put as an audit, right?

Comment: Maybe see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275954/what-to-do-with-duplicated-answers), it's a nearly exact copy of an existing answer, only nowhere near as helpful

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think that in Late Answers queue, we check for NAA/VLQ, spam, R/A, not for plagiarisms.

Comment: If there are existing answers, especially popular and/or accepted ones, and particularly if the answer is /very/ late, I would expect the answer to explain what it is doing there, i.e. what new insight it contributes. Otherwise, I would vote it down (after commenting to request such explanation, and giving the answerer a few hours to respond, which I have never known one do). Basically late answers are in my opinion guilty until proved innocent.

Answer (score 6):

Read the review guidelines. Than pay close attention when reviewing. Hope that will work

Comment: @double-beep Even without looking at the other answers on the question, you can tell that it's not a good answer at all, which is what the Late Answers queue is for. You'd have a bit more of a case (only a bit more) if the answer looked high-quality at first sight (regardless of plagiarism), but it isn't.

Comment: @double-beep Have you read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)?

Comment: Apparently the point of my answer was far too subtle. There were no accidental typographical errors here. If you did not find this answer to be useful or enlightening, well, that's kind of the point.

Comment: @double-beep on mobile right now and extended copy paste is rather a chore. Couldn’t find anything pertinent for this case? Read carefully. Particularly the _”subtle stuff”_.

Comment: @double-beep Considering that answer is considered _the guidance_ for that queue, it's not a big surprise that other comments kinda repeat what it says. If you find yourself unable to grasp the point, I guess I wont be able to help you. I would be repeating what others said as well.. Between that q&a and shog's answer you _should_ be set as to not get caught anymore. Bottom line: you chose poorly, and the audit is there to help you not chose poorly in other cases. No biggie.

Comment: @Cody, sorry for mangling your "then/than" point. Was (is) lost on me as well. Your subtlety is a match for my English level.

Comment: @yivi Compare to the answer that double-beep reviewed. Notice any similarities, in both style and substance? The point is, if an answer is completely useless, it's reasonable to delete it. My answer here is *completely useless* in that it did not answer the question. Yet...strangely...it got accepted. That's lost on me. I would have expected at least one NAA flag by now. (And don't feel bad about your language skills. They seem fine. My subtlety is lost on plenty of native speakers. Maybe a weird sense of humor, or just unfunny.)

Comment: Feeling pretty dumb now, but with a smile. The original, audit answer was already forgotten by this point. On my (weak) defense, phone screens tend to focus you only in one thing at a time. At least I didn't upvote the answer. I will now, in appreciation of its weirdness.