# I'm resigning as a moderator from all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-resignation

I'm resigning as a moderator from all Stack Exchange sites, effective today.

I didn't make this decision lightly, frivolously or suddenly.  A [persistent pattern of corporate missteps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965), and [a monumentally deplorable moderator dismissal](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel), has compelled me to re-evaluate my relationship with Stack Exchange.

You won't miss me much.  The latest crop of moderators has done a fine job at keeping the infamous Stack Overflow Moderator Flag Queue™ under control.

Special thanks to [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9), [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) and all of the CMs, who have been nothing but supportive, helpful and educational, even when I was probably a bit more volatile than I should have been.  My problems with the network have nothing to do with them.

It has been a privilege serving you.

Comment: You are probably one of the moderators that has maintained the diamond for the longest time. Sad to see you step down... :(

Comment: It has been a privilege **being** served by you. SE.com: wtf?!

Comment: So sorry you're leaving - you will be sorely missed. Thank you for everything and all the best for your future.

Comment: I really don't know how to vote here: up to show you my solidarity or down to express my sorrow for losing an excellent mod :-(

Comment: I've been on the verge of leaving the site for years, but after the recent managerial clusterducks I just don't have any faith left that things would get better instead of gradually getting worse and worse. Hold the door, I'll get my coat.

Comment: Always looked for your input and opinions to shape my own during great SO debates. I’m sorry to see you go!

Comment: It isn't like I had completely nothing to do on a Sunday afternoon doing chores but to look at the nuclear fallout that's suddenly hit the network. Why do I feel like I've been under a rock?

Comment: Sometimes resigning is drawing a new path for success.

Comment: Any chance we can find out what this actually is all about? We've heard what moderators had to say about the CoC change, and what consequences that had, but it's hard and strange to judge what's going on without actually knowing the cause.

Comment: I am sorry. Thank you everything. I am not sure how and if SE will respond, but my gut feeling says that this is the last straw for me as a user as well. I've been on SO for 7 years, almost 5 years of unbroken consecutive days. I'll cease all activities for now and wait for an adequate reaction, but hopes are thin. I'll be sorry to leave this community for the users and I'll stay as long as I can provide a voice to help in protest - but I detest how SE is presenting itself right now and won't stay if nothing changes.

Comment: @ErikA  Monica's post is probably the best summary we're going to get unless someone leaks the contents of the moderator chat in question:  https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel

Comment: @Makoto To your defense, this has largely been confined to confidential spaces and is only now starting to hit the bigger channels. Be glad you weren't under *that* rock, though. ;-)

Comment: Downvoting because I hate losing a good mod. I am not even sure the “voluntary workforce” model is going to work for mods in the future. This sucks.

Comment: @yivi there's only so much we can do to support our moderators who have something resembling real leverage with the company. If you support Robert you upvote.

Comment: Actually @AndrasDeak; didn’t downvote. It was a figure of speech. Not that voting these posts will have any effect whatsoever. This has gone way beyond voting. This really sucks.

Comment: Sadly, I am not surprised.  I have been expecting such events since 'Three Wheels on my Welcome Wagon':(

Comment: You were a bedrock to this place for so many years. It had a great run for way longer than I'd have ever expected and was (& still is) a resource providing great value to all the world. You were a big part of that. Thank you for your service.

Comment: It is definitely hard to see long time deep contributors go, but this is sometimes the way of life. I don't begrudge anyone after ~10 years wanting a change.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: This goes a little deeper than one moderator's mid-life crisis.  When an organization has clearly lost its footing, sometimes the only option left is to move on.

Comment: Thank you for this. To be fair, even though I would miss you, I am happy for you because Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Organization doesn't deserve your services. Stack Exchange has assumed that it can move forward with killing its core group and just relying on the content which is present, totally ignoring the fact that it was the core group which brought them to the point they are. The callous replies to your post is just a cherry on the top of the cake.

Comment: It's sad to see you go, but it's also hopeful to see someone taking action against SE now. I speak for everyone when I say that you were a great moderator.

Comment: I did not say it didn't @RobertHarvey but ten years is a _looooong_ time anywhere, no matter how amazing it might (or might not) be

Comment: I have no regrets.  I've learned a ton from the SE network over the years, and hopefully, in my own measure, I've been able to pay it forward.

Comment: Thanks for your service. I look forward to seeing you around the network, at least for the short while I'll likely be around for. You've definitely been one of the more level-headed people I've dealt with.

Comment: As the person who will become the oldest elected moderator on Stack Overflow after Robert steps down, and as someone who has just been back on the site a full month as of today after vanishing for 5, I'll be issuing a statement of my own soon (and I may not necessarily even do it on Meta). For now, I'd like to focus on some side projects I'm excited about for the coming week or so, and I've sent Robert my utmost regards in private.

Comment: @BoltClock♦: Perhaps an interview with a newspaper or other major publication could be interesting, because it is rather unprecedented what's happening right now on *the* biggest computer/programming site in the entire world.

Comment: @Cerberus: I don't think it's quite the public spectacle you think it is or needs to be. I just want to issue a personal statement so everyone knows what's going on in my life and what my own plans on here are going forward. And while this is unprecedented in the network's history, it's not really the business of anybody outside of the network.

Comment: @BoltClock♦: OK, I understand. I just thought, the light of day might provide a new perspective, but I understand that choice is nor for everyone.

Comment: Damn that is such a shame.

Comment: @GhostCat: As far as I understand it was locked for getting too many incendiary comments, or just plain too many comments too quickly, several of which were getting flagged. Would be nice if the notice could be edited. I can unlock it now, but people gotta promise not to say things that have already been said... we know and agree how objectionable management's actions were and don't need *more* comments saying the same in varying combinations of words. We have enough on our plate as it is. We don't need more flags over any of this.

Comment: @BoltClock So, you are basically saying: when there is a kettle full of water on a hot boiling plate, we better make sure that kettle is really nicely sealed, because otherwise, bad things are going to happen? OK, seriously. I understand you point, and obviously we mere mortals do not see flagged-and-deleted comments (only the reasonable ones left behind) ... but still: I am wondering if it is really "helpful" to the community in the long run. If there is a large negative sentiment, that can't be "locked out".

Comment: @GhostCat: There is no shortage of critical comments with dozens of upvotes - I think the negative sentiment has been quite well-articulated and hardly "locked out". Some of the later comments we've been getting weren't even constructive criticisms so weren't adding value. I see Modus Tollens' comment and it looks fine - I suspect it was deleted because Rob (who's been the one handling the comments and flags) decided to retract what he said, thereby making their reply obsolete.

Comment: Thank you for all the good work. I sincerely hope that StackExchange takes a deep look into its consciousness and turns around soon in order to preserve the value of the work that has been invested here. On the other hand I'm rather pessimistic usually. The reply by Sara Chipps, which I would like to downvote, but can't, is not really confidence inspiring in this regard.

Comment: '*Research update: Improving the question-asking experience*' - SO, please do some research on how to treat mods/power-users who spend their valuable, free time to keep the site clean and what the appropriate way is to treat them. The air is pungent with the stench of your hypocrisy.

Comment: @BoltClock *"And while this is unprecedented in the network's history, it's not really the business of anybody outside of the network."* - I disagree. Stack Overflow has a part in the day-to-day work of millions of programmers, most of them not contributors. Its ability to help those people depends upon having good contributors. If we're at the point that the company, at Sara's bidding, is going to start purging users whose personal beliefs it finds insufficiently progressive, we're going to lose a lot of people, its mission is going to be damaged, and with it, so too will our whole industry.

Comment: @Mark Amery: Fair enough, I hadn't considered that perspective. I just don't want to be the one speaking on behalf of anyone, not even Robert, but myself. And I certainly don't want to be put on a podium. But I can certainly agree with letting this get more attention - the community, especially us moderators, need to speak up. I think the underlying CoC issues are going to be an added complication much better handled separately, though. But you know how media is - sensationalist.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I hate everything about this.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I would suggest that firing a long-respected moderator for questioning (not violating, but merely asking questions about) "a policy that isn't even written down yet" has much more to do with the community's response than any particular political or religious view. So far, the only even borderline disrespectful discussion I've seen about anything political or religious were Aza's comments on Caleb's post. Whether it's this post or the one Bergi linked, respectfully, I'd like to request that at least one of these be featured. This is important to the community.

Comment: @reirqb saying the user only “questioned” the policy is inaccurate and a mischaracterization of the events that transpired.

Comment: After reading more about this, I have to agree. The only solution is to leave the site. Everybody should go. I also refuse to live under the proposed changes in the new CoC.

Comment: This has made the news https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/

Comment: I like that your gravatar is the kanji for "beauty" (美). Very classy, and a fitting emblem for an exemplary career here. Good luck to you.

Comment: Thank you @RobertHarvey. You certainly have been help in my career.

Comment: I was surprised to see your name on a question closure today.  I guess this is a [Minnesota Goodbye](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Minnesota%20Goodbye)?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Robert has resigned as a moderator, as you can tell by the absence of a ♦ after their username. AFAIK they haven't said that they would quit using Stack Overflow, and they can still vote to close questions just like any other user with enough rep points.

Comment: @MarkRansom: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites-effective-today/389907#comment730684_389907

Comment: Glad I got here just in time https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhUvF.png

Comment: @will: That's not half as bad as using all caps for your SQL.

Comment: I was sorry to see you go, Robert, and I'm sorry that I've had to join you. It was a pleasure serving with you.

Comment: To the pedantic people trying to close this question: *stop*

Comment: @Pekka "Pending pronoun policing piques political protest" That reporter had way too much fun summarizing the situation.

Comment: To those voting to close as unclear: What about this is unclear?

Comment: This is unfortunate. SE leadership evidently believes that "peace" is equivalent to lack of opposition. This is, of course, false, as disagreements are a normal part of human interaction. Hopefully community feedback will help them reevaluate this position.

Comment: Robert, it's been an honor working with you as a moderator over the years. I'm sorry that my new job and a bit of travel kept me from seeing this right away, and even more sorry to see you go. The volunteer effort you put in as a moderator made it a better place, and I always enjoyed our conversations. Best of luck in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Brad. I'll see you around.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you might be interested in this follow-up question asked by another user https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390493/what-could-stack-exchange-inc-do-to-make-you-want-to-stay

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry to shove a microphone in your face, but I feel you should have a voice....care to comment on [why you're suspended on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336339/why-was-robert-harvey-suspended)? Is there some place you might be able to discuss that besides on the SE network?

Comment: @mason: You can find me on LinkedIn.  https://www.linkedin.com/in/masterdeveloper

Comment: @mason: And for what it's worth, they have my permission to fully discuss the suspension on Meta.SE.  I was not offered an explanation, other than the usual canned response.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you. Sorry for the insult. We disagreed on some stuff, but you're a good guy and this isn't fair.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right now I really, really wish that you "earned" your suspension (even though this is very hard for me to imagine)... if you didn't that would be the worst case scenario...

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC: I've been very careful to not cross any lines, other than the fact that I've been very critical of the company.  Maybe they're just trying to slow me down a little; I can hardly blame them for that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "other than the usual canned response." What was the response? & what was the warning before the response (If any)? Just curious

Comment: @dustytrash: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vfJr.png

Comment: @RobertHarvey was there no warning!? The answer on the meta post says there was

Comment: @HFBrowning: I can't find the original warning on my account.  I think it's reasonable to assume that its content was substantially similar (if not identical) to the suspension message I just got.

Comment: I'll just say this: if this is about quelling disagreement by wrapping it in a cloak of faux politeness (or worse, looking for bigotry where there is none), then you might as well just close down Meta.SE, permanently.  Because you've just demonstrated that you have *no genuine interest in community feedback, and we're all wasting our time here.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey all warnings are also sent to your email

Comment: @Sklivvz: I don't see it in my email box.  I might have deleted it.

Comment: Sorry to hear this happened. If you don't like my speculation, feel free to indicate so and I'll stop. I've seen people talk about a lot of comments being deleted on Meta. In your screenshot the mail talks about *rudeness*. Might it be the case that the ban is automatically issued after a number of *rude or abusive* flags? Anyway, I have only been active on Meta very recently but I've already come to know you as a serious user and it is very weird to see you suspended.

Comment: JJJ.  No.  It requires specific intervention by a moderator.  There are machine-enabled bans, but they don't look like this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey All I can say for all your recent posts and comments +1000. I haven't seen anything that would even remotely deserve suspension and if you say that you didn't cross any lines I believe you 100 percent.

Comment: OK, I received some more information about the suspension.  [Here is a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw2Q5.png). The first link is [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334051/support-for-gender-pronouns/334053#334053).  I posted the comment about "a manual you can read" under [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336233/102937); the post I linked to in that comment is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336164/102937).

Comment: The "Well, how clueless do you have to be" comment was in response to yet another new user [posting a programming question in Meta.SE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyhy7Z71qzE).  That one is the only comment I feel sorry about.

Comment: wait, is that supposed to point to peewee?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is that supposed to link to YT?

Comment: okay, I get it. after watching the clip itself. carry on.

Comment: Anyway, well-played SE.  I'll happily wait out the 7 day suspension.  See what a little transparency can do?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've posted your comments in [a community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336356/387405) on the relevant meta question. I think it's good for people to know what happened and I welcome the transparency on your part.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You walk the minefield all day and then you slip over banana at your front door ;)

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC: Ain't that the truth.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm considering asking for a mod to post the 44 flagged comments mentioned in your suspension message, so we can judge for ourselves whether they were truly rude or abrasive. Would you object to me doing so?

Comment: @MarkAmery: You can if you feel like it.  I'd prefer a meta post asking for better transparency in mod messages.  I used that boilerplate message all the time when I was a mod, but never understood why people got confused until I was suspended myself.  The truth is that boilerplate message is every bit as impersonal as the corporate boilerplate SE has been using on Meta, and it provides no information that would help a user figure out what he's done wrong, other than the admonition "we think you were rude."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Heh. I've been grumbling on Meta about generic boilerplate criticism being unhelpful and discourteous for a long time, albeit usually [in the context of the community dishing it out on new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367861/1709587). I guess I'm glad to finally have you on side, at least when it comes to the principle. Sorry about the circumstances.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As for whether to ask the specific question about you or the general one about detail in suspension messages, it seems to me like it'd be reasonable to do both, which I shall.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Works for me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey might I suggest to you [what I previously suggested to Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336230/is-there-any-concerted-action-that-could-be-taken-to-ensure-that-monica-not-be-f/336304#comment1112263_336304). TL;DR take the lead in a respectful campaign for transparency. Coordinate the campaign from an off-site chatroom (like Discord), make sure it stays civil under the leaf of experienced (former) mods. Come up with a coherent and consistent message which we can put in our bios, user names and profile pics (and Twitter, if some insist).

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you think that can be at all helpful? Something like *Transparency Now! Sincerity Soon :)* in reference to Seinfeld's [*Serenity Now!* *Insanity Later :(*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ow_9MglZrhs).

Comment: @JJJ: You give me more credit for being influential than I am actually due.  I've been very active on Meta for the past couple of weeks precisely because I thought I might be able to influence enough people at SE to think "what in the hell are we doing?"  But clearly I was wrong about that.  Stack Exchange is going in a very specific direction now, and nothing is going to change their minds.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it's because we're not working together. Any campaign needs a familiar face that can rally the troops. You are known, you have a message, many users agree. The only downside to leading a campaign is that it takes time and effort and it may wear you down. If you're interested, discuss it with a few other former mods. If you do decide to go down that route, I'll join and so will many others, I think. Getting the message from the interested few (on Meta) to the wider community is key if you want to get somewhere.

Comment: @RobertHarvey now you're giving SE more credit for being influential than they're actually due. They are idealists, they're not campaign savvy. They're playing [salami tactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_tactics). When many users unite, they cannot divide and they will have to concede, either by taking a moderate stance or by answering to the powers above (investors and their board of directors).

Comment: @RobertHarvey FYI, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336485/200582) is the general-case question about mod messages you proposed, and I've described my actions regarding *your* specific case at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336339/why-was-robert-harvey-suspended#comment1114114_336356.

Comment: @MarkAmery: FYI, I stopped issuing mod suspensions on Stack Overflow ages ago.  There are plenty of automated systems that stop the most egregious bad actors automatically, and other mods are better at sussing out sock puppets than I am.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How about the post it referred to? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Any chance you could post more screenshots covering the full content of the post? Surely there was *something* more than what you're showing here to provoke a suspension?

Comment: Please use chat for further discussions on this, Robert and Mark.

Comment: @Robert I am so sorry for what happened on Meta. I guess we will not be seeing you there anymore. I hope you will stay here :)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Thanks.  I will still be around, on Stack Overflow and Software Engineering.

Comment: Link to the chat created per Cody's request above: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203777/room-for-mark-amery-and-robert-harvey

Comment: So what now that an ["agreement" has been reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio)? Will you ask for reinstatement?

Comment: @JL2210: [No.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390659/102937)

Comment: @Cerbrus  I don't want to engage in rollback hell. Per meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400751/956880 links to removed questions should be removed. The link is effectively dead. That 10k users can see these posts is not relevant. 10k have this privilege for curation purposes, not because we have a two tier repository with some links visible for high-rep users and not for the rest. If you still disagree I can open a question about this issue here in Meta.

Comment: It is a notice for moderators, @AnonymousCoward. Moderators can still see the relevant history in a deleted link. It shouldn't be edited out. Also, the link isn't normally visible in the question. It's a comment for mods / editors to notice. But by all means, confirm this with Meta.

Answer (score 422):

I don't get it.

Thousands of unanswerable questions a day come in, the experts and teachers who made this site what it is are leaving faster than new ones join, the moderation tools never get improved, comments under poor questions become harsher, and suddenly someone tweets that the site is full of elitist, misogynist snobs and then a blog gets posted stating that we should all be more friendly to one another, while question quality keeps dropping and it's harder and harder for people to find interesting questions to answer.

Meanwhile, the site has turned into "debug this code for me", and loads of users happily oblige, not contributing to the knowledge base it was once supposed to become.

And now a mass exodus of moderators occurs. What happened in between? What is happening to the site, can someone succinctly explain that to us out of the loop?

Comment: Yeah this should probably be a new question altogether, but then I have a lot more to say and I don't want to take the flak.

Comment: _"What happened in between?"_ A mod got fired for a being at risk of _potentially_ violating an upcoming CoC change. (At elast, that's what I gathered from this situation)

Comment: Fair warning: this is the type of thing you get sucked into. [You can start here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/332043). There's a lot of friction and internal problems, and some mods have had enough. It's not just the surface of the site that's having problems

Comment: I think the core issue is that SE no longer has any goodwill left in the bank.  At this point, the disillusionment and feeling of not being heard has resulted in people cutting their losses and moving on.  Like Robert said, it wasn't this, specifically, but just the last thing that broke the camel's back.  I anticipate more departures, mostly non-public.

Comment: [I asked that question myself.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387878/why-are-a-lot-of-users-including-moderators-upset-about-where-so-is-going)

Comment: I'm just tired.

Comment: Seems to me it has passed the point of "debug this code for me", and gone to "write this code for me".

Comment: @fbueckert I agree, the good will was heavily primed by the originators, fueled through their copious blog posts.  Now, it's sold, and it's even more than typical "business first".   I get it, SO can't live without business, but they're burning their contributors, so in a few years, they'll have no answers, just questions.

Comment: Early on everyone was willing to overlook the shortcomings as it was an exciting time building the knowledge bank.  Now there is little new (in the general case) to be added so it really comes down to "how do I do x old thing but in y new language".  Which is quite boring really.  So, the shortcomings of old become more obvious and disillusionment sets in.  Pretty typical lifecycle of a knowledgebase.

Comment: The decline really became noticeable shortly after Atwood left in 2012.

Comment: When you push all the content creators out, and close off all of the avenues for users who want to have factually informed opinions, all you leave as qualifying questions are those which are solvable with an example of a broken problem; you could call this set of questions "debug questions". That a large portion of users playing in these queues both lament the situation but also demand fixable code as a criteria creates a problem not easily solved.

Comment: One experienced and knowledgeable user is worth exactly the same as a clueless user who can't type in a hello world example on his own: what the advertisers pay for one unique visitor. Losing one power user who might hurt the feelings of at least two beginners is therefore a net gain for the company. (Until the advertisers realize that they are no longer targeting power users, but clueless students who must sit through CS classes.)

Comment: @berendi well... When all the experts are gone and the newbies DONT come here anymore cause it's not the place for good answers anymore .... Ad revenue will dwindle :/

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite right @berendi. Where CPM advertising is concerned, a user is worth the ad impressions they view per month. A user who visits many more times per month and sees many more pages per visit, is worth more than a user who visits rarely and sees few pages per visit.

Comment: @berendi let's do a little math. This site gets, like, 2 or 3 thousands questions from new users a day, that's 2-3 thousands visitors a day, right? On the other hand, [traffic stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) for SO say it gets 10 _million_ visits a day, do you see the difference. It is probably reasonable to assume that these millions visits come to answers made by skilled, knowledgeable "power users" (because these millions visitors want useful quality content, not senseless homework dumps). Looks like power users content is what brings ads revenue

Comment: @gnat Yes, millions of visitors come here to find quality answers. Do they find it now? Probably yes. Will they find it in 5 or 10 years, if the signal-to-noise ratio suffers? "Inclusion and respect" (yuck) towards people who are not willing to learn, but want their homework done by someone else will hurt overall quality. Not tomorrow, but in a few years. The site owners want quantity, not quality, that's fine because it's their property, but I'm afraid they have to do it without the free help of experts and mods, because no self-respecting person will be motivated to remain on SO for nothing.

Comment: in my opinion the question quality drop over time is the site's own success coming back to bite it: so many people have asked "good" questions that increase site knowledge that there are very few left. The way around this is to wait for new technologies to emerge that require new questions to be asked

Comment: And if you talk about it on meta, you get censored. Check my SO, MSO, and MSE profiles for the ridiculousness they last put me through.

Comment: I could not agree more. Especially when it comes to the root cause. I talked to two trans friends of mine, and they were **not** amused: "Altercations like this do not do any good. They rarely succeed, and while they might change a few things here and there, they have the potential of creating even larger rifts." Qed. As for the quality of the questions, the quota of "do-my-work-for-me" questions seems to continuously rise - we need more good mods, not less. I am sorry to see him go, but I have the utmost respect for something ver rare today: his personal integrity.

Comment: *loads of users happily oblige, not contributing to the knowledge base it was once supposed to become* - I cannot agree more with this. I see more and more users, with a high reputation (20K+ sometimes even much more) that seem to be in an absolute need for higher reputation. Answering question that **are** duplicates that **they** even have answered in the past, most of the time just copy-pasting their own previous answers. What's going on? This just grows the amount of "legitimate" questions when they are not. Once a question has been answered and eventually accepted, what moderation occurs?

Comment: @MrUpsidown well, [I myself am sometimes guilty of that...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310698/stack-overflow-fatigue-has-your-usage-motivation-dropped-off/310709#310709)

Comment: @CodeCaster that process is well described in your post, indeed. Just try to enforce the rules and you're the bad guy. Earlier this week, I down-voted an answer from a 100K+ user which was just plain wrong, commenting on it (nicely) and mentioning it was wrong and inviting him to look at my answer for a correct solution. Guess what happened? He deleted his answer immediately and, surprisingly, my correct answer was down-voted seconds later. What kind of behavior is this? Things have changed. And certainly not in a good way. High-rep users used to be people you could trust.

Comment: @EternalHour And make my homework for me.

Comment: "Meanwhile, the site has turned into "debug this code for me", and? A site, like SO, dedicated to programming couldn't have more fundamental questions that debugging code, which is like 90% of a programmer's job. Everyone (including me) knows how to answer questions where you just need to be a good Google searcher, but helping people figuring out the actual problem in the code, no, no no, this is uninteresting, in a website dedicated to programming?

Comment: @nbro I'm not against debugging questions, but a lot of them literally come in like _"This is [not enough|all] of my code and it does not work"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, that's really 99% of the problems of a programmer. But sometimes a question needs more clarification, yes.

Comment: @EternalHour: More like "**Code. Quick!**".

Comment: I'd like to know what well-informed individual is calling SE a bunch of misogynists, they clearly aren't well acquainted (or willingly ignorant) of the site.

Answer (score 234):

Well, this was ***unexpected***.

All I can really do now is thank you for putting in the effort you did to help along Stack Overflow.

Don't be too much of a stranger.

Comment: *Stack Overview* ... great name for a fresh community ...

Comment: I miss the Swype keyboard, @rene...

Comment: I'll still be around, albeit at a lower level of participation, and minus a binding vote.

Comment: [Ed Cottrell also resigned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389991/839601)

Answer (score 154):

In the time I've taken a break from the site, I've spent more time being made aware of what is going on than when I was active on the site.

I'm sorry to lose you. I have a great deal of respect for you and enjoyed modding with you.

I can't upvote your question - the downvote is because we're losing you.

Comment: Stepping away affords perspective.  It's been awhile since I've been in the Teacher's Lounge.  I was unprepared for the dumpster fire that I found there this morning, but not exactly surprised.  Alas, SE seems content in merely pouring more gasoline over it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I remember you from when I first joined the network. I've been away 10 days and the last few days have probably spent more time involved in the network than as a mod. 
I will miss you :'(

Comment: @JL2210 I think I need to come back. We be losing too many people :'(

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't think it is a bad thing. SE is steering into a certain direction and the latest actions just accelerates the "departure" of old members who would leave anyway, just at a lower pace. I guess we need to accept that things are changing :/.

Comment: @Tom yep, I've been saying that for a while. The old site is dead. It's changing. It's hard to accept change, but it's the way of life really and it's now in the hands of a corporation - so $$ I'm not passing judgement on that either way, just stating it as a fact

Comment: @YvetteColomb: Of all of the mods on the network, yours was the one voice in the wilderness that not only welcomed change, but embraced it.  I will miss you as well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey after being on the panet >0.5century [I'm a realist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ou4FXC3aK_8&list=PLPX8v0923px3m6pwXg6yE9UbVbbBBjZBG&index=2). I don't like rallying against things I cannot change. [Serenity prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_Prayer) and all that :D Please consider changing your mind. I don't want to go back to a mod chat room without you. I left while you were on holiday.

Comment: You've stepped down (which I understand)? Makoto is not a mod? Now Robert Harvey? And this psychosis across other SE sites? WTF is happening to SE?

Comment: Glad you saw the light @YvetteColomb

Comment: @Yvette: You were the (rare) voice of reason on meta. I don't go there usually but hearing that you even think about leaving makes me even more mad at the powers that be. I think I'll take a break from adding to the site.

Comment: @TaW I just came back with all this .. amazing... unfolding of.. God knows what.... I'm actually speechless

Comment: I am so sorry to see you go. I voted for you and you are one of my favorite mods. Sometimes we were travelling different roads, but I believe we shared the same goal.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thank you so much. I like seeing you around fwiw. It's comforting to see other strong women active on the site. I know a lot of people don't like me saying that, but I do like to have women around me in the sea of programming. You've always been level headed, you would make a good moderator yourself. Though now is not the best time to entice people into the position!

Comment: Thank you. I am currently on strike https://stackoverflow.com/users/4267244/dalija-prasnikar?tab=profile showing support for all moderators, the ones that have left and the ones that are still here. This is not something I decided overnight, it has been boiling for a long time. I believe now is the time to make the stand and show that without community there is no Stack Exchange. If we cannot have civil and open discussions about all matters then we have nothing.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I support this action. You may be interested in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCST82Vkaio

Comment: @YvetteColomb You don't have to be a rocket scientist to know that making a video whilst driving is insane.

Comment: I'm glad you decided to step down as a mod. Not because of your actions, but because you tried *so damn hard* to make things better and always seemed like you were getting beat up over it. I didn't always agree with your meta posts, but they always came from a good heart with a desire to help. Thanks for trying so hard, you've done some good. Enjoy your mod retirement.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor roflmao! fair call my friend, fair call!

Comment: @Will thanks, I'm wondering if I've done any good ttytt. This is an unprecedented disaster for the site.

Comment: @Yvette unprecented.... For now. Give it time, the powers that be will likely find a worse way to slip up soon :(.....

Comment: @Patrice new CEO - crisis on the site, at least one person's head will roll. A hopeless incompetent debacle.

Comment: Is there a reason why "Please feature Robert Harvey's resignation notice" was deleted 21 hours ago? I can see the deleted question and my answer but no one else's. I don't see any comments complaining about the OP, although they were heavily critical of one mod's behaviour. The mod who deleted the page is a different one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA from what I can see people are struggling and the mods are just batoning down the hatches to make their own lives easier. It's not intended censorship, it's more about keeping posts manageable, less bodies on the ground, less people to handle flags and monitor comments. I'm not sure that we won't lose more moderators. So it's a time we just need to develop patience until there's some kind of status quo. Literally there's not enough people to manage the sites.

Comment: Wat?! Now you're user3956566.?

Comment: @jl2210 yes. I’m not the only person to use the generic username

Answer (score 127):

Losing moderators of your standing must mean something.

I sincerely hope that SE learns something from this and don't just use their iron fist as a castle in which to hide and rule and expect everyone to unquestioningly keep tilling the fields while the gibbet swings above them...

Comment: I would hope too, but wouldn't count on it.  I just called out a "big time" contributor for calling me a junior (when I've 9 years in), calling the questioner's code "total nonsense" and calling the questioner's user name "probably a troll account", and for my efforts, the comment was moderator deleted.  I'm seriously considering deleting my account StackOverflow has crossed a line that makes me (a nine year user) ashamed to contribute to it's success.

Answer (score 105):

Goodbye.

We *will* miss you. Thanks for all that you've done for our community.

Comment: I came here to say exactly this. You will be missed. To some of us you ARE Stack Overflow, together with many others who spent years (whether elected or not) moderating the site, its content, and being a force for good. It's a shame to see someone as capable, active and level-headed leave the site. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 89):

Sorry to hear this Rob, always enjoyed working with you back when I held my diamond. Sounds like SE is being infected by the Woke virus with this preferred pronoun nonsense - but it's not my site so I don't have a freedom of expression leg I can stand on. Can't say I use the SE network much any more, and will likely use it less now. Which is a shame because there are some great folks such as Tim and Shog who've always been fair, rational and very supportive of the *unpaid volunteer* diamond mods.

I think the way the community and volunteer mods have been treated by SE is a bit cheeky despite the many hours of work they/we put into making this work from the beginning.

Also my heart sank upon hearing a certain individual arrived out of the blue as a "Director" despite having so little meaningful activity on SO. I didn't think this particular individual would be well suited to their new role, and recent events have just proved this.

Wee bit of an edit here. In Sara Chipps' blogpost here:

> https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/

She blethers on about:

> The team formerly known as DAG (Developer Advocacy and Growth), now
>   part of the Community team, started by rolling out the ***Tag
>   Synonyms*** Refresh.

As far as I know, I was the "community member" that suggested Tag Synonyms back in 2009:

> [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)

Now I'm not getting all salty here, but y'know SE at least try and attribute major feature enhancements that were driven by the community. Sure there are minor enhancements which are hard to track down and attribute, but the big stuff (which I'm trawling through just now on old meta posts) that moved the community along, how's about some gratitude.

SE has a serious "tin ear" problem with the unpaid folks from back in the day that made this site successful that now pays your rent.

I'm kinda in a f*** you mode right now. This wasn't the community I joined back in '08, sure communities change, money has to be made, but the abstracted away corporates are living off of our original work and ideas when it was Jeff, Jarod and Joel....and the *community*.

When I handed back my diamond mod, all I got for the hundreds of moderation hours was a fricken mug and some shit pens (it's ok Tim, you'd no control over that). You need to do better than this, how about useful stuff like some Amazon vouchers for exiting diamonds to show your appreciation? You spent hundreds of thousands of dollars on new offices and data center environments, but you don't treat mods with any kind of respect or value. We helped get you here.

I kinda feel this "honour to be a mod" is a racket. It's unpaid work. Hell at least if I drive an Uber or cycle madly round the city as a Deliveroo driver I can at least get some kinda payback. But SO/SE has played on this "great honour" for far too long. Maybe it's time diamond mods do actually strike and maybe test the law for what in my country would be called "unjust enrichment", especially if SE is able to carry through an IPO.

We used to talk about the terribleness of [help/question vampires](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=question%20vampires) but I kinda feel SE Corporate has also in a way sucked our community dry, and sucked the goodwill out of many of us.

Comment: Amen, at this point it is probably best for a site-wide strike of the mods. No question about it, you lot **have** been doing tens of thousands of hours of (often thankless) unpaid work over the years, making SE what it is, and this is how the site has treated you? It makes my blood boil and I'm just a lurker, I can't imagine what this feels like for you mods... probably akin to a knife to the chest.

Comment: Moderators certainly deserve more respect. On the swag issue, I also believe they've stopped distributing a goody bag for 100k users. Just another indication of the trend away from a community. Of course, it's false economy: don't appreciate what makes the site work.. and it'll stop working for you.

Comment: All this managing makes me quite sad, for a while I was quite happy just helping people, trying all the while to keep site quality even when it became ineffective (rep haverseters go well with help vampires, but I don't care so much about rep anyway). Now the behavior of few leaders unbalances this to the point I don't want to contribute anymore. I don't want to give to people that only take, and especially the way they do it. Some moderators are so eager to cover what are obvious bad decisions to so many, with censoring and trying to hide it from the "mainstream" users, that it made me sick..

Comment: @jpp - I crossed the 100k boundary a couple of weeks ago and wasn't offered a goody bag.

Comment: I crossed the 100k boundary over two years ago. The only acknowledgement I got was seeing the decimal place on my rep disappear.

Comment: @duskwuff, Well, yeh, I never expected (or got) anything when I reached 100k.. I never contributed for the swag, but a personalised email is a relatively cheap alternative to say thank you.

Comment: True. SE *could* certainly show some gratitude to valuable users/mods that do spend a lot of time trying to make these communities better. But what about **huge** companies, like Google to cite only one, who direct most of their users to SO for *first-level support*? Do they show any respect/gratitude to users who have helped thousands of people to use **their** products and therefore **helped them making money**? No. They don't. And I don't think they'll ever do. I am seriously questioning myself now about whether I should stop or continue to do this for them, getting nothing in return.

Answer (score 83):

I'm sorry we're losing you.

They say if you want to judge someone's character give them power over someone else and see what they do with it.

You were always willing to put in the extra bit of effort to help and explain. Tough, fair, and kind. We were a better site with you as a mod.

I deeply regret that you can't say the same of those with power over you.

Answer (score 65):

**We're sad to see you go after serving the community for 8+ long years**. You were a mod even before lots of people including me, joining this community.

You people did a really hard work to create a good space for us to join, ask, answer and interact with others and we never felt getting abused or trolled by any others, unlike many other communities.

The hardest part of any community is its starting phase, where the new joiners won't follow rules, abuse others, post stupid things, etc. Even if I was not a member of any SE community at that time, I know how much you suffered to build up this community.

Many of us were aware of the things happening last week and it's really hard to see a moderator (Monica) who helped the community and its members feel safe, without charging a single penny in this 21<sup>th</sup> century, has been mercilessly removed by the director(s).

Not to mention, a former SE employee also got his account suspended for 5 long years recently, which makes us think that at least some of the new staff in this company never want anyone to speak against them and don't want to hear any criticism.

When considering the publicly available information, as you said, I don't believe the community managers have anything to do with this, other than following orders. We interacted with many CM's like Shog, Jon, Tim, etc. in the chat rooms, and they work hard to improve the community. But still, they're employees and they've to follow orders by the employer.

While the one among the two, behind this successful company, Joel is going to step down as CEO (we lost the main one, Jeff Atwood, years ago), we people are really confused about the future of this community.

Comment: _"a long term SE employee also got his account suspended"_ Have you got a source for that?

Comment: @Cerbrus I forgot to add _former_

Comment: Still, is there a source on that?

Comment: @Cerbrus I opt to keep their identity private. To address your question, he was an elected mod on this site, then worked for Stack Exchange for more than a year. After discussing this on a chat room, I came to know that he got the network wide suspension for 5 year because he tweeted a screenshot of a threat mail he received from the company, which says _if you share anything against this company, your account will be suspended_.

Comment: Then you should delete that part. You won't back that claim up (which is understandable in your situation), but for us it is currently no more than hearsay. It is quite similar to what @SaraChipps does in her answer, she claims a mod violated the CoC, but refuses to back it up.

Comment: @Tom, ok. I'm not keeping it private. It's Jeremy Banks who got suspended for a tweet and he was elected in 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/election/6

Comment: I can think of one user who you might be referring to. But that doesn't seem to be related to this particular fiasco

Comment: @SurajRao I mentioned it here because the behavior from the company in that issue is highly unacceptable. any company should be able to take negative and positive reviews from user. A company can't threat it's users that _if you say anything bad, your account will be suspended_. This is not the site, it were last year. It has completely changed.

Comment: Suspensions in Stack Overflow isn't private but I thought to keep their identity because I was following that for last 2 years. In this specific scenario, he didn't violated any CoC or done any malpractice. I thought about it again and In this case, I don't believe there's a problem in disclosing their identity.

Comment: It seems the tweet has been deleted already, too bad. But thank your for the information.

Comment: @SagarV Jeremy Banks has a long past of being a loud dissenting voice and thorn in the company's side. Don't get me wrong, I like the guy and think he's usually in the right, but to suggest that he was "suspended for a tweet" leaves out a *lot* of the history - even if there's no more history there than the bits I happen to know about, which is likely not the case. (I also don't know what the Tweet was that you suggest got him suspended or the evidence that that Tweet was what tipped things over the edge - can you explain?)

Comment: @MarkAmery After seeing Jeremy with 1 rep, I discussed it with few other members in a chat room of MSE (not here in SO) and the points I came to know are, _i) he lost his job in 2017 mass layoff. i) When he said something, he got a mail from this company telling if you say anything bad, your account will be suspended iii) He then tweeted a screenshot of the mail. His twitter account is private, unfortunately some SE staffs are following him._ 
They also told me that, some mods lifted his suspensions per sites and SE suspended him again and told those mods not to do that.

Comment: And we just have to take your word for that. surely, that's documented somewhere?

Comment: @Cerbrus suspension reasons aren't public. And in this case, from the information I got, mistake is done by the company. I don't think they will disclose it. I'll try to create a transcript for the chat history. (it happened ~ 2 weeks ago. I had to find those messages)

Comment: @Cerbrus here's the link to first message(my bad. not 2 weeks ago. It happened last week) https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926668#7926668 and the other 2 messages https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926678#7926678 https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926680#7926680

Comment: @SagarV Sonc is not an employee not even a moderator. You can't use his messages to back up your (wrong) assessment of what happened with Jeremy.

Comment: @rene agree. But we will never get an internal view because of the company's policy. Even if they try to fix all issues, I don't think they'll disclose all information. In such cases, we don't have any other way than relying on general information available. Sonic mentioned the tweet, which was deleted already and we've heard Jeremy's side. As long SE keeps their part private, I've to stand with Jeremy. When considering Monica's removal, I don't think Sonic is wrong

Comment: It's still just hearsay and speculation, and maybe only borderline relevant to what's happening here, if at all...

Answer (score 46):

I remember you from my very first week here. That's years ago.

Thanks for your great service and for all your help!

Answer (score 45):

Sorry to hear it.

You've done a great job here.

Best of luck.

Let's hope the company doesn't muck up what has become an indispensable site.

Answer (score 28):

Hey man,

It must have taken a lot to get to this point. The technologies I use overlapped with yours and in the past I have enjoyed our encounters. You often provided sage outlook to users in need, and the behind the scenes work you did was probably not heralded, but was certainly noticed.

I hope the resignation is something that you can work out somehow going forward. If not, that is just the way the world works sometimes.

All the best.

Comment: Don't ever want to get into this because lets face it, it's a power keg waiting to explode. But, the minute you introduce race, gender, religion or pseudo political agenda you will have conflict. SO is a resource for "Programmers" *(simply: a person who writes computer programs)* if we kept it that way there would be no conflict. I'm here to answer programming questions, I have no interest in what your personal beliefs, political views or sexual orientation are I just want to help solve programming problems. I realise this wouldn't work for every community I'm specifically referring to SO.

Comment: @Lankymart - I don't really disagree with what you said, but I am curios, *why* did you say it *here* in this comment?

Comment: Well it doesn't make much sense now as the other comments have been removed.

Comment: Ah, I never saw the other comments. I mean, its a fair point to make, and it seems like it got a lot of upvotes, so no need to remove it now. I just had no clue what the context was and it didn't seem to fit as a direct response to my answer. No worries.

Comment: The original comment was a quip by me that played on the *"Hey man"* *(in relation to what has transpired in regards to gender pronouns)*, it was sarcasm so probably why it was deleted.

Comment: Not looking to rehash. The intro was meant as a form of familiarity since we have chatted from time to time.

Comment: I know, enough said.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know you but as a Stack Overflow user I would like to thank you and hope this decision to make your later times full of happiness.

Answer (score 21):

Hope you are going to do more awesome work.

We will miss you.

Thanks for being here and whatever you've done for our community.

Answer (score 18):

It's sad for you to leave, but many thanks for your investment in the Stack Exchange community. Your work and assistance will live on.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to hear that. I wish you the best luck for the future. I hope everything will be as you wanted.

Thanks for everything you've done for Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 6):

And the would-be thought police strike again. What a shame. And what a loss for everyone else.