# Suspended users can make invisible comments on Collectives articles

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, account-suspension, articles

I was looking at the activity tab of a suspended user and noticed that they had made a comment while suspended:

[image: Screenshot of an anonymized suspended user's profile. The date "Jun 24" on a comment is circled.]

The link in that activity item leads to [this Collectives article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android), but *"hello world maybe a bit longer"* is nowhere to be found there: as far as I can tell, this comment is only shown on their activity tab. I thought it might be that deleted comments still show on your user page, but when I make and delete a comment on an article it doesn't show in my activity tab.

It's also possible to [see the comment on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1536867):

[image: A screenshot of SEDE. There is a table with two rows, the last one has text and metadata for a comment that says "hello world maybe a bit longer"]

And to look at [the comment flagging dialog for that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/flags/comments/120402446/popup).

What's going on here?

Comment: I knew who this user was before I even looked at the question body. JB

Comment: It was submitted as feedback, not as a comment. It is visible when editing the article. The system currently gets kind of confused due to the way that feedback is stored.

Comment: @richardec See the comments on this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites#comment730763_389918

Comment: Eye opening, @Smitop. Thank you.

Comment: @animuson but how did the do anything like that _during suspension_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for submitting this issue. There are a few things to address from this post, so here goes:

- As was pointed out by @animuson in the comments, what you're seeing is "feedback" for the article, which is a way for people to notify the article's author that the article needs some sort of update.  These aren't shown in the UI for articles like normal comments -- only article editors will see them on the edit page for the article.
- On July 1st, 2021, (a week after the suspended user left the article feedback) we closed the permissions hole that allowed suspended users to submit article feedback.
- As you probably guessed, article feedback is implemented via the commenting system, which is why they show up in the SEDE results and were showing as a comment on the activity tab. Unfortunately, the fields needed to differentiate article feedback from article comments aren't in SEDE.  It's possible we'll change this in the future, but not at this time.
- As of today, we've removed the article feedback items from the user activity tab. Note that feedback items are still visible to mods/staff on the article timeline and on the mod-specific page for looking at a user's comment history, so they aren't *completely* hidden from the UI -- thus allowing mods/Community Managers to see and deal with potential bad actors (harassment and other unwelcome interactions).